# Why do my .class files seem to be corrupt?

Tags: java

Im new to programming. The language im learning now is java. I got some .class examples from my school's portal, tried to open it with Notepad++ and it appeared some text with random characters that i've never seen. 
here's the "code":

Êþº¾   4 Š F G H I J K L ^ _ ` b c d e f k l m n o q r u ‰ t y z { | } ~     8      9      <      A      6
  7
  B
  C
  4
  ;
  4
  :
  D
   5
   =
   >
   ?
   @
   E ] P ] W p i t U t j t s v X w Q x g € O  M ‚ N ƒ O „ h … Y † Z ‡ O ˆ [ %c contido em %c. %c Ã© MaiÃºscula %c Ã© MinÃºscula %dÂª letra do alfabeto. %n %s tem %d pontos. %s valores diferentes ()F ()I ()Ljava/lang/String; ()V (I)C (I)F (I)I (I)Ljava/lang/String; (I)V (I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Ljava/io/InputStream;)V -(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; (Ljava/lang/String;)V <(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/PrintStream; '(Ljava/util/Locale;)Ljava/util/Scanner;   ?  
AxB = [%d,%d] Bits (1..40) Code Equipa Intervalo A Intervalo B Jogos realizados Letra Ljava/io/InputStream; Ljava/io/PrintStream; Ljava/util/Locale; Ljava/util/Scanner; 
Nascimento NÃ£o se intercetam. ParabÃ©ns, faz %d anos. Sem soluÃ§Ã£o. Tem %d anos. US Unicode = %d VitÃ³rias e derrotas [Ljava/lang/String; a a b c append charAt in java/io/PrintStream java/lang/Object java/lang/String java/lang/StringBuilder java/lang/System java/util/Locale java/util/Scanner next  nextFloat nextInt nextLine out print printf toString   useLocale x = %f !      
 t j    t s     ] P  a        *· )±      t N  a         ² !¶ 1¬      t S  a        ¸ &² !¶ 1¬      t M  a         ² !¶ 0®      t R  a        ¸ &² !¶ 0®      t Q  a        
¸ &² !¶ /¶ *¬      t O  a         ² !¶ 2°      t T  a        ¸ &² !¶ 2°

 t U  a   .     "» Y· +;² "2¶ ,¶ ,¶ -K² $*¶ '±     Œ t V  a   .     "² $» Y· +;² "2¶ ,¶ ,¶ -+¶ (W±      \ P  a   «      Ÿ»  Y² #· .² %¶ 3³ !½ YSY
SY    SYSYSYSYSYSYSY SY
SY
SYSY
SYSYSYSYSYSYSYSYSYS³ "±

The code is quite simple, we only had 3 weeks of classes until today

There's only avaliable the .class files to download, nothing else.

Just a heads up, some words are in Portuguese, so you might not understand them :P

I would appreciate any kind of help solving this problem since im new to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's how it supposed to look like if you open it with a text editor! The .class file has Bytecode, try `javap.exe`

Comment: `.java` files have the code you are probably looking for, `.class` is what you get after compilation and it is not really readable.

Comment: A `.class` is a _binary_ file. Its not meant to be human readable. You either need the source file (`.java`) or use a bytecode viewer, such as `javap`, as suggested.

Comment: .java == sourcecode (as in text readable by both humans and compiler) .class == compiled bytecode. So, this is pretty normal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which of those characters have you never seen?

Comment: @shmosel Ÿ u ask?

Comment: I went to cmd and wrote: "javap.exe (name of the file)" and it appeared me this:

Comment: @pvg L̲͖͡i̱̝̙̯̻k̴̦ͅe̖̝͇͡ ̣̘͉̱̦̹Ì͚̗͖̤̗̫ͅ ̴͖̤̩̥̞s̳͉̫̣̳͜a̷̻̭ḭ̱͇͔͉̪d̕,̮̙͟ ͏̭͔̤̤̰̼j̤̱̱̪͟ͅu͏̙̠̟̝̱s̮̹̪̙̞͝t ͞c̞̘̯̺̳͓u̲͓̫̥͎̦͍r͇i̗͖o̬u̘̣̞̪s͍̣̞̯̜.̨̳̘͚͈̦̜

Comment: Useless tidbit of information, the Unicode string `Êþº¾` in hex is CAFEBABE, the "magic number" for a Java class :)

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't open them with notepad.
`.class` files are compiled Java files.
They contain the binary simplification of the Java source code.
They are meant to be understood by the computer (the JVM, to be precise), and not human.

You may look for the `.java` files, which contain the Java source code which is human readable.
Or you may want to decompile them, if you need to know the original source code and you don't have it.
You could do that using `javap.exe` or really any online disassembler.

Another possibility is that you were given them so you could import the functions in them (Though this seems unlikely).

It all depends on what you were intended to do with them.

Comment: and can i convert them to .java?

Comment: @AlexT. you can. That is what a [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) is for. There are many for Java. This isn't nearly as good as just getting the original source file from whomever wrote it.

Comment: @AlexT. What purpose were they given for?

Comment: exercise from school

Comment: @AlexT. But what are you supposed to do with them? Are there another files? Is there an instructions file?

Comment: @Obicere i decompiled it and at the beggining of all of the lines it says "protected" or "private", so... i guess i cant access them?

Comment: @AlexT. Probably not. Both are valid Java.

Comment: @Neo its an exercise that we have to do and the teacher just uploaded the exercise file (i guess) but in .class only

Comment: @AlexT. It's possible you were supposed to decompile the files. It might be a mistake? Anyway, what's in the files?

Comment: @AlexT. What is the exercise? Maybe you just need to use them and then there is no need to see the source.

Comment: @Neo i could show you in this comment but it surpasses the characters limit

Comment: @Oleg its to ask the user to write 2 numbers (like 2 and 4) and then other 2 numbers (like 3 and 5) and see if the gap of numbers from each group of the 2 numbers (group A is 2 -> 4 and B 3->5 for example) intercept. In this case, there's an interception (between 3 -> 4). We then need to say if there's or not an interception and if one of the groups is totally inside the other.

Comment: @AlexT. You can upload it to a file sharing website and post a link, if you want.

Comment: @AlexT. Why do you need to download a `.class` file for that? This is just an assignment you need to do on your own.

Comment: @Oleg i honestly dont know. They're just there near the exercise's description. I just assumed they were to download to see the answer in case we have problems